# Facebook graph api m.mid vs m.id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm retrieving messages from my page, but notice that the messages have two different id types.

on most of the messages they have an id as such:

```
"id": "m_id.363733227087070",
```

however some of them are formated as

```
"id": "m_mid.1374165333681:48689d90e8f7fa5e77",
```

What is the difference between m_mid and m_id?  I cannot find any documentation on why some messages have an ID that is m_mid and some are m_id.  Additionally, they m_mid has some sort of hashed number after it, any idea what this hex represents??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you find a definite answer for this?

From my observation, the first message in a conversation has id with the format `m_id.<numeric id>`. All subsequent messages have id with the format `m_mid.<numeric id>:<hex hash>`